# Backup and Restore SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, smo

I need to backup (using C#) a SQL 2005 Database to a *.bak file.  From that file, I am trying to restore into a new Database on the same exact server.

The backup works fine and then my C# code calls the restore method and it appears to be working until it finally "timesout".  I checked the "innerExceptions" and they reveal that the RESTORE made it to 90 percent and then returns the exception.

Below is the code I am using to BACKUP AND RESTORE.

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong?  It must be a timeout parameter somewhere that I can set but I do not know what it is or how to do it.

```
public class JRBackupRestoreDB
{
    public static void BackupDatabase(String databaseName, String userName, String password, String serverName, String destinationPath)
    {
        Backup sqlBackup = new Backup();

        sqlBackup.Action = BackupActionType.Database;
        sqlBackup.BackupSetDescription = "ArchiveDataBase:" + DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
        sqlBackup.BackupSetName = "Archive";

        sqlBackup.Database = databaseName;

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(destinationPath, DeviceType.File);
        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];

        sqlBackup.Initialize = true;
        sqlBackup.Checksum = true;
        sqlBackup.ContinueAfterError = true;

        sqlBackup.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlBackup.Incremental = false;

        sqlBackup.ExpirationDate = DateTime.Now.AddDays(3);
        sqlBackup.LogTruncation = BackupTruncateLogType.Truncate;

        sqlBackup.FormatMedia = false;

        sqlBackup.SqlBackup(sqlServer);
    }

    public static void RestoreDatabase(String databaseName, String filePath,
    String serverName, String userName, String password,
    String dataFilePath, String logFilePath)
    {
        Restore sqlRestore = new Restore();

        BackupDeviceItem deviceItem = new BackupDeviceItem(filePath, DeviceType.File);
        sqlRestore.Devices.Add(deviceItem);
        sqlRestore.Database = databaseName;

        ServerConnection connection = new ServerConnection(serverName, userName, password);
        Server sqlServer = new Server(connection);

        Database db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        sqlRestore.Action = RestoreActionType.Database;
        String dataFileLocation = dataFilePath + databaseName + ".mdf";
        String logFileLocation = logFilePath + databaseName + "_Log.ldf";
        db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        RelocateFile rf = new RelocateFile(databaseName, dataFileLocation);

        System.Data.DataTable logicalRestoreFiles = sqlRestore.ReadFileList(sqlServer);
        sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[0][0].ToString(), dataFileLocation));
        sqlRestore.RelocateFiles.Add(new RelocateFile(logicalRestoreFiles.Rows[1][0].ToString(), logFileLocation));

        sqlRestore.SqlRestore(sqlServer);
        db = sqlServer.Databases[databaseName];
        db.SetOnline();
        sqlServer.Refresh();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are trying to restore into a database on the exact same server, you could just create a stored procedure to this, passing the mdf and ldf path.

Comment: I have tried adding a timeout parameter and trying it now.  Would a stored procedure be more efficient with performance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a value with `ServerConnection.StatementTimeout` to see what happens?

MSDN reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.common.serverconnection.statementtimeout.aspx).

Comment: I am trying the StatementTimeout connection right now.  It takes some time.  Speaking of which...  Would a Stored procedure as Chris mentioned a better performer in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

This is something that'd be pretty darn easy to do in plain sql...

Have you considered trying it that way?  You just have to write the sql script or procedure to do it and then run it.  This is what we do (for a different situation, but similar):

```
backup database {{DATABASE NAME HERE}}
to disk = N'{{FILE_NAME_HERE}}'
    with
        name = N'{{BACKUP_DATABASE_NAME_HERE}}'
GO

restore database {{NEW_DATABASE_NAME}}
from disk = N'{{FILE_NAME_HERE}}'
    with
        file = 1
go
```

Comment: also very helpful.  Since I have it working using my C Class, would the performance be better in just calling a stored procedure?

Comment: @dellbingham I'd ask the question another way - what are you gaining by abstracting SQL commands away in your C# code? At every shop I've worked/consulted, the application code acted as a conduit to call stored procedures, not as a replacement for T-SQL and DDL.

Comment: @dellbingham Best way to find out which performs better is to try it both ways. (not a perfect measure, but `System.Diagnostic.Stopwatch` is an awesome tool).  If it's helpful +1 it ;)